# How to add terms below matrices and add markings to this cross product calculation

Tags: matrices, math-operators

I have to write a math script with a cross product like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}a_2\cdot b_3-a_3\cdot b_2\\a_3\cdot b_1-a_1\cdot b_3\\a_1\cdot b_2-a_2\cdot b_1\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I add the terms below the matrices and draw the lines as shown?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's not entirely clear what your question is about. Is it about how to typeset what you wrote down by hand, including how to insert the green and red lines, or is about how to perform the underlying calculations? Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe you can try to come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This would make it easier to identify the things you need help with. As for typesetting the equation without the colored lines, there should be some examples on this site already.

Comment: I want to typset the handwriten formula. So I don‘t habe a working example. The colored Lines are not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility with `nicematrix`. The entire expression is one matrix. Then you can use `nicematrix` and `tikz` commands to draw the lines from cell to cell. The parentheses are added using the `\SubMatrix` command in the `\CodeAfter` (i.e., after the matrix is drawn).

Remember you must compile twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded automatically by nicematrix

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[create-medium-nodes]
  a_1 && b_1 && a_2\cdot b_3-a_3\cdot b_2 \\
  a_2 & \times & b_2 & = & a_3\cdot b_1-a_1\cdot b_3 \\
  a_3 && b_3 && a_1\cdot b_2-a_2\cdot b_1 \\
  a_1 && b_1\\
  a_2 && b_2
  \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix({1-1}{3-1})
    \SubMatrix({1-3}{3-3})
    \SubMatrix({1-5}{3-5})
    \tikz[name suffix = -medium, thick]{
      \draw(1-1.west)--(1-3.east);
      \draw[red](2-1)--(3-3);
      \draw[red](3-1)--(4-3);
      \draw[red](4-1)--(5-3);
      \draw[green!80!black](3-1)--(2-3);
      \draw[green!80!black](4-1)--(3-3);
      \draw[green!80!black](5-1)--(4-3);
    }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix} \\ a_1 \\ a_2
\end{array}
\times
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix} \\ b_1 \\ b_2
\end{array}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2\cdot b_3-a_3\cdot b_2 \\
a_3\cdot b_1-a_1\cdot b_3 \\
a_1\cdot b_2-a_2\cdot b_1
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the thing I needed. Can you give me a hint to typeset the colored lines and the first line?

Comment: @JensGundelwein - Drawing the colored lines would appear to be a job for the tikZ package. Unfortunately, I've never learned tikZ. May I suggest you post a new query, in which ask for advice on how to draw the colored lines?